# How to handle this alert or frame using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, chinese-locale

https://niioa.immigration.gov.tw/NIA_OnlineApply_inter/visafreeApply/visafreeApplyForm.action

Something pop up after I select the first item and I cannot handle the popup . I do not know what it is, it's not alert. and I cant find the frame for the (switch to frame)

its a Chinese website....
so I have pasted the elements that's loaded after I selected the first item

```
<div class="blockUI" style="display:none"></div>

<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6; cursor: wait; position: fixed;"></div>

<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 1011; position: fixed; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 450px; top: 539.5px; left: 119.5px; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 3px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 140px; overflow: hidden;"><div id="showWarnMessage1" style="">
    <table class="application" style="margin: 10px;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <p class="Prompt" style="text-align: center">注意</p>
                <p>除香港居民持有BNO護照及澳門居民持有1999年前取得之葡萄牙護照外，持有外國護照，不適合辦理本許可。</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <div>
        <input class="btn" value="確認" type="button" onclick="$.unblockUI();">
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get past the pop-up:

```
chromedriver = "your_path"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get('https://niioa.immigration.gov.tw/NIA_OnlineApply_inter/visafreeApply/visafreeApplyForm.action')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="isHKMOVisaN"]').click()
```

And then this last line is what gets rid of the pop-up:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="showWarnMessage1"]/div/input').click()
```